# Kendo grid update does not send grid data to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid defined like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TaxCertApp.ViewModels.Article7YearsViewModel>()
          .Name("Article7YearsGrid")
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
          .Scrollable()
          .AutoBind(false)
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(s => s.ID).Hidden();
              columns.Bound(s => s.SetType).Title("Type").Width(50);
              columns.Bound(s => s.SetYears).Title("Tax Year(s)").Width(50);
              columns.Bound(s => s.SetDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(50).EditorTemplateName("Received");
              columns.Bound(s => s.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(50).EditorTemplateName("Order to Court");
              columns.Bound(s => s.Amount).Title("Amount").Width(25);
              columns.Bound(s => s.RefundSavings).Title("Refund Savings").Width(50);
              columns.Bound(s => s.Notes).Title("Notes").Width(300);
          })
          .ToolBar(toolBar =>
          {
              toolBar.Create();
              toolBar.Save();
          })
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(1000)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ID);
                model.Field(p => p.SetType);
                model.Field(p => p.SetYears);
                model.Field(p => p.SetDate);
                model.Field(p => p.OrderDate);
                model.Field(p => p.Amount);
                model.Field(p => p.RefundSavings);
                model.Field(p => p.Notes);
            })
            .Read(read => { read.Action("Article7YearsFetch", "Case").Data("BuildObject"); })
            .Create(create => create.Action("EditingCustom_Create", "Case"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("EditingCustom_Update", "Case"))
            )
        )
```

And this is what the view model looks like:

```
public class Article7YearsViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SettlementID { get; set; }
    public int FileNum { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string SetType { get; set; }
    public string SetYears { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? SetDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string RefundSavings { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

}
```

When the grid loads, it looks like this:

[image]

When I modify some of the data in the grid and click on the Save Changes button, the grid data should get sent to the controller.  This is what the controller looks like:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult EditingCustom_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, IEnumerable<Article7YearsViewModel> yearData)
    {
        if (yearData != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var record in yearData)
            {
                var ID = record.ID;
                var SetType = record.SetType;
            }
        }

        return Json(yearData.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

I have a breakpoint set in the controller on the if clause.  When I hit the breakpoint, I look at the value of yearData.  It contains null.

Are there other fields/indicators that I need to set up to have the grid send the grid data to the controller?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the binding attribute:

```
public ActionResult EditingCustom_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<Article7YearsViewModel> yearData)
```

See this [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing).